# External HP Mouse Suddenly stopped working In Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, laptop, mouse, touchpad

I have an external HP mouse which was working fine with this Toshiba laptop, now suddenly it is not working anymore only on this laptop. On other laptops, the mouse is working fine and any other external mouse is also working fine on my laptop.

Steps taken :-

1. Reinstalling Drivers Many times after plugging and un-plugging the external mouse
2. Updating Synaptic Drivers for my touchpad
3. Making sure, mouse is enabled in BIOS
4. Rebooting many times

Laptop Specs :-

Windows 8
Toshiba C640D
Intel I5 2430M @ 2.4GhZ
4 GB DDR2 Ram

Comment: Does it work as expected in Safe Mode?  How about if you log onto Windows as a different user?

Comment: @techie007 finally I was able to resolve this after reading an asnwer on SU only. It was the removal of the MotionInJoy Drivers.

Comment: Nice!  Well please post an answer to your own question, siting the other SU question/answer as a source -- it'll help others who find your question find the solution.

Comment: @techie007 And done :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, solved it using another answer on SU. The problem had nothing to do in the end with the fact I am on an Toshiba Laptop , it stemmed from the fact that I had MotionJoy drivers installed for using a Playstation 3 controller over USB. That works fine, however, the MotionJoy driver package also contains drivers for internal and USB bluetooth dongles, and Windows randomly decided to use the MotionJoy drivers for my mouse and keyboards USB receiver.

I solved it by going to the Control Panel -> Devices and Printers. Under the 'Unknown Devices' heading there was the USB receiver/USB Mouse. Right click -> Properties -> Hardware -> Select HID Compliant Device -> Properties -> Under the General Tab, Change Settings -> Driver Tab, click Uninstall Driver, and check Delete this driver. Click OK, and restart the system.

Let me restate, this is only applicable if your USB mouse or keyboard is not working, and you have the MotionJoy drivers installed on your system. I didn't look for a workaround, because I do not use my PS3 controller on the computer anymore.

Source = [Troubleshooting the Microsoft generic USB HID drivers](https://superuser.com/questions/375203/troubleshooting-the-microsoft-generic-usb-hid-drivers)